# svn pecl (php) with subversion 1.7 - compiler error

Tags: php, svn, pecl

Old installsion is broken.
I tried to reinstall / upgrade with **pecl upgrade svn** and get this error

> /tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_contents_changed’:
>   /tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c:3746: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared >/tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c:3747: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at> /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
>   /tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_props_changed’:
>   /tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c:3794: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
>   /tmp/pear/temp/svn/svn.c:3795: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
>   make: *** [svn.lo] Fehler 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed
>   I cant find the developer area for beta or svm/git build http://pecl.php.net/package/svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug report has been filed for this issue:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60767

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem 5 years later...

After `phpize` and `./configure`, edit the generated `Makefile` file with a text editor.
Change the line

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2
```

to

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=c99
```

now `make` and `make install` should finish successfully.

Comment: Although there is an accepted answer, the only way I was able to install this php extension for svn was to use RPM. In my case (RHEL 6.9, PHP 5.6) I found an appropriate RPM file at https://centos.pkgs.org/6/remi-x86_64/